# multiselect dropdown with listbox

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to create a drop down with multi select and listbox that would show the sub categories of selected items from drop-down.

E.g. The drop-down contains the main category - Fruits, Vegetables and Animals. And this main category contains sub categories example -Fruits(Apple,Banana,Mango), Vegetables(Onion,Tomato, Cucumber), Animals(Lion,Tiger, Elephant)
so, if the person selects from a drop-down let's say Fruits and vegetables(multiselect), so according to the selection from drop-down the listbox should show with lists -Apple,Banana,Mango,Onion,Tomato,Cucumber. And if the person selects Fruits,Vegetables and Animals(multiselect) from the drop-down.
Then the listbox should show with lists -Apple,Banana,Mango,Onion,Tomato,Cucumber,Lion,Tiger,Elephant.

Hope you may understand !!

Condition is that the drop-down should have multiselect and according to the selection of drop-down and the listbox should show the summation list of sub categories.
And secondly want to remove dublicates from the displayed items in listbox at last.

(these aren't the real values I know the sub categories of  Fruits, Vegetables and Animals does not contain any dublicates but i want the condition to be applicable for real time work)
.If the displayed listbox contains some dublicates should be removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere :(

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220334/discussion-on-question-by-bhushan-agrawal-jsr-multiselect-dropdown-with-listbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the next approach, please:

1. Insert the next code in the module sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim rngDV As Range, oldVal As String, newVal As String
 Dim arr As Variant, El As Variant

 If Target.count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler
 If Target.value = "" Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
     Target.Offset(0, -1).value = ""
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Exit Sub
 End If
 
 On Error Resume Next
 Set rngDV = cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
 On Error GoTo exitHandler

 If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

 If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   newVal = Target.value: Application.Undo
   oldVal = Target.value: Target.value = newVal
  
   If Target.Column = 7 Then
    If oldVal <> "" Then
      If newVal <> "" Then
         arr = Split(oldVal, ",")
         For Each El In arr
            If El = newVal Then
                Target.value = oldVal
                GoTo exitHandler
            End If
         Next
         Target.value = oldVal & "," & newVal
         Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit
      End If
    End If
   End If
   writeSeparatedStringLast Target
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub writeSeparatedStringLast(rng As Range)
  Dim arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, El As Variant, k As Long, listBox As MSForms.listBox
  Dim arrFr As Variant, arrVeg As Variant, arrAnim As Variant, El1 As Variant
  Dim strFin As String ', rng2 as range
  
   arrFr = Split("Apple,Banana,Mango", ",")
   arrVeg = Split("Onion,Tomato,Cucumber", ",")
   arrAnim = Split("Lion,Tiger,Elephant", ",")
  arr = Split(rng.value, ",")

  For Each El In arr
    Select Case El
        Case "Fruits"
            arrFin = arrFr
        Case "Vegetables"
            arrFin = arrVeg
        Case "Animals"
            arrFin = arrAnim
    End Select
    For Each El1 In arrFin
        strFin = strFin & El1 & ", "
    Next
  Next
  strFin = left(strFin, Len(strFin) - 1)
  With rng.Offset(0, -1)
    .value = strFin
    .WrapText = True
    .Select
  End With
End Sub

'Firstly run the next Sub, in order to create a list validation in range "G1":
Sub CreateValidationBis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("G1")
 
 With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                   Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Fruits,Vegetables,Animals"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
 End With
End Sub
```

a. Run `CreateValidationBis` Sub (if not already done). It will create a list validation on "G1" cell, for the categories you mentioned.

b. Test the updated solution.

c. Send some feedback about haw it works...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220404/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-multiselect-dropdown-with-listbox).